# How to render html.erb partial dynamically depending on the origin of the render call?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, render, erb, partial

I've got a `_topbar.html.erb` partial with element for that I render from the index of homepage.
I want to call the same partial in other pages, but depending on the endpoint that's rendering it, I want to display a different content.

Is there any way to apply a dynamic content based on the origin of the render on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using `current_page?` So you could do something like:

```html
  <!-- _topbar.html.erb -->
  <% if current_page?(posts_path) %>
    Here are my posts
  <% else %>
    Check out my <%= link_to "posts page", posts_path %>
  <% end %>
```

(docs are [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F))